# Detail of solving the quintic by radicals

Tags: abstract-algebra

D.S. Dummit says:

> Expressions in the roots of the Lagrange resolvents that are fixed by even permutations ($(12345)$ and $(25)(34)$)  are elements of the fixed field $
> \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5 \cdot \mathrm{discriminant}})$.

Could someone explain why is this true?

The text above is from an article on the internet 'Solving solvable quintics', page 12, lines 8 and 9. The pages are not numbered.

Link:(https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.23.4322&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Comment: Dummit's statement seems like it is from a context in which it is explained for example how the numbers 1-5 are associated to the permuted variables, and what these variables mean for the quintic being investigated. It would be good if you included this in the question.

Comment: Is this then an exercise which appears after a section discussing the quintic? If so i was asking for context in terms of definitions etc. in that section.

Comment: @Gerard Please add context to your question. What is the source of this quote? Dummit and Foote's abstract algebra textbook? Dummit's paper on solving solvable quintics? Somewhere else? Please also include more of the setup surrounding your quoted passage.

Comment: Text of the question made more specific